# How can i allow users to set react native app icon on the fly after deploying it

Tags: react-native

Users of the app are divided in different sections depending on which a particular app icon will be shown. When a new section of users is created, how can we upload and set new app icon without having to update the app on playstore or appstore?

Ive tried react-native-change-icon but it required the icons beforehand. We want to set completely new icons without having to update the app.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.